# problem with cors using react and rails with DEVISE

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, devise, cors

I'm having a problem doing sign_out by devise in the api.

Let's go... I have a react application and a rails-api backend.

I call all kinds of methods from my api, several gets, some posts... etc.

even with devise's own gem I can create an account, and then log in without problems.

now I went to implement the sign_out and boom! CORS error.

```
const logOut = async(event) => {
     const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/sign_out`;

     const requestOptions = {
       method: 'DELETE',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'access-token': Cookies.get('access-token'),
         'client': Cookies.get('client'),
         'uid': Cookies.get('user_email')
       }
     };

     const res = await fetch(url, requestOptions).then();
     console.log(res); // doesn't even get here
}
```

follows the error, when I click on the button that calls the function logOut:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
     at logOut (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:378:23)
     at chainedFunction (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:95443:9)
     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:58759:18)
     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:58803:20)
     at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:58860:35)
     at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:58874:29)
     at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:63018:7)
     at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:63044:11)
     at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:63055:9)
     at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:63064:7)
```

EDIT ----------

The request call doesn't even make it to the API.
I keep paying attention to the API and the call doesn't even get there.

—not a comment

Comment: The request call doesn't even make it to the API.

I keep paying attention to the API and the call doesn't even get there.

Comment: Change your call to this to see if you can get more information. ```fetch(url,  requestOptions)
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))```

Comment: I try. buy it says that resolve doest not exist. So i changed to console.log(response);... Well.. in console shows: `Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.15.5:3030/auth/sign_out' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` and more `DELETE http://192.168.15.5:3030/auth/sign_out net::ERR_FAILED`.

Comment: Add that to the question -- not a comment